# Json parsing fails when testing through mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to develop some test suites for my nodejs app using mocha
My app recieves a  json from a request ,parse it and insert to DB
While providing the json through html like

```
form action="http://localhost:3000/json" method="post"> 

    <textarea name ="json" cols= 30 rows=10>



    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name ="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

my application runs smoothly.But running the below test suite code using mocha

```
it('Test api',function(){
    chai.request(server)
    .post('/json')
    .type('json')
    .send({"json":{"i":"J"}})
    .end(function(err, res){
        res.should.have.status(201);
        done();
    })
});
```

I get the trace as `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` while parsing the json.
Please help.

Comment: A code snippet from where the error is occurring would be useful. Try stringifying the JSON as most request parsers will expect stringified json in the request body. If you include the code that parses the incoming request we might be able to give more than a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar errors trying to JSON parse a JSON object.  Agree with Mitch, see what happens when you stringify your JSON like this..

`.send(JSON.stringify( {"json":{"i":"J"}}))`

more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify